# Does it make sense to do the power analysis if one of the sample proportions is 0%?

Tags: python, statistics, statistical-test, experimental-design, sample-size

Can we have any sample size if one of the sample proportions is 0. I mean even the slightest difference detected between the two groups would be because of the treatment in this case, and hence I do not see any reason why the power analysis should be done.